# SwfitUI set the whole app to right to left

Tags: xcode, swiftui

How can I globally set the app from Left to right layout to Right to left layout in the new SwiftUI 2 framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set corresponding environment value at root view

```
@main
struct AppMain: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
        }
    }
}
```